# The integral $I(a,b)=\int_0^1x^a\log^b(x) \space dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I found a formula for the integral $$I(a,b)=\int_0^1x^a\log^b(x) \space dx$$ By just differentiating the integral $I(t)=\int_0^1x^t\space dx $ under the integral sign  b times and evaluating the resultant $b$-th derivative at $x=a$. The formula that I came up with states that $$I(a,b)=\frac{(-1)^bb!}{(a+1)^{b+1}} $$ A quick check on some values of $(a,b)$ on desmos like $(1,1), (3,4) ,(1,2)$ quickly verifies that the formula for the integral is true for at least these values of $(a,b)$. My question is: how do I find all pairs $(a,b)$ such that this formula makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side is only defined when $a \neq -1$ and $b \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$. Moreover, since $|\log x| \geq 1$ on $(0, \frac{1}{e}]$ we have $$\left\vert\int_0^1 x^a \log^b x \,dx\right\vert = \int_0^1 x^a |\log x|^b \,dx \geq \int_0^\frac{1}{e} x^a |\log x|^b \,dx \geq \int_0^\frac{1}{e} x^a \,dx.$$ In particular, our integral diverges if $a \leq -1$.

For the remaining values of $(a, b)$, namely, $a > -1$ and $b \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, we can establish that the formula holds in a different way: Substituting $u := -(1 + a) \log x$ gives that the integral is equal to
$$\frac{(-1)^b}{(1 + a)^{1 + b}} \int_0^\infty u^b e^{-u} \,du,$$
but applying integration by parts $b$ times gives that this latter integral has value $b!$, establishing the identity.

**Remark** More generally, for $a, b \in (-1, \infty)$, using the usual integral representation of the gamma function shows that
$$\int_0^1 x^a (-\log x)^b \,dx = \frac{\Gamma(1 + b)}{(1 + a)^{1 + b}} .$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As I understand, by introducing the gamma function we somehow remove the counting number nature of b (that came from differentiating b times or integrating by parts b times) and generalizing the result to the reals even though the predescribed nature of b is still there.

Comment: Yes, that's right. For nonnegative integers $n$, $n! = \Gamma(1 + n)$, and for all $x$ in the domain of $\Gamma$ (namely, all real numbers, except for the nonpositive integers) $\Gamma(1 + n) = n \Gamma(n)$. Moreover, $\Gamma$ is the unique log-convex function that has these two properties.

Comment: Put another way, $n \mapsto \Gamma(1 + n)$ is the natural extension of $n \mapsto n!$ to nonnatural arguments. Somewhat amusingly, this function maps $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), you can differentiate under the integral sign as long as your function and all the derivatives you are taking are continuous. In your case differentiating only adds additional $\log(x)$, which doesn't make your function discontinuous (at $0$ or anywhere else) as long as $a > 0$. Moreover, since you want to take $b$ derivatives, $b$ is necessarily a non-negative integer for your argument to work. Hence you arive at $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $b \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Using the [measure theory statement of that theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement), you can in fact show that it suffices to assume $a > -1$.